# Can grantees from dba_*_privs be logged into if not found in dba_users table?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I have 35 grantees from the dba_sys_privs and dba_tab_privs tables that do not appear as usernames in the dba_users table. They are not assigned as roles in the dba_role_privs table. Can they be used/logged into?

Comment: Are you sure they're grantees?

Comment: They are being granted privileges, but they could be roles or they could be users. In any case there are not appearing in either the roles or users tables

Comment: Do you mean that they do not exist in `dba_roles`?  Or `dba_role_privs`?  `dba_roles` lists all the available roles.  `dba_role_privs` indicates which roles are granted to different users.  It is entirely possible to have roles that have privileges granted to them but which are themselves not assigned to any users.  It is also possible that the roles are granted to other roles (which you would see in `role_role_privs`) rather than being directly granted to other users.  Is there any chance you could show us exactly what queries you're running and exactly what results you are getting?

Comment: @JustinCave I can't show you the query or results. Sorry. I have been using the dba_role_privs tables and might request the role_role_privs table. I don't have access to run them myself. Just doing the analysis. Thank you!

You answered my question when you said roles could exist that aren't assigned to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Justin Cave's comment should explain 34 of your 35 values: a role can be in `DBA_ROLES` but not in `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS`.

The last value is probably `PUBLIC`, a [special role that works differently than other roles.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_privileges.htm#CIHHGIGB)

```
--Grantees who are not users or roles.
select * from
(
    --Grantees
    select grantee from dba_sys_privs union
    select grantee from dba_tab_privs
)
minus
(
    --Users and roles
    select username from dba_users union
    select role from dba_roles
);

GRANTEE
-------
PUBLIC
```

[You can kind of make it look like you logged in as PUBLIC if you use `as sysoper`](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00000060.htm), but that doesn't really count.